# How to save a binary file (zip) on Jenkins per job, like with HTML Publisher

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I am using the [HTML Publisher Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/HTML+Publisher+Plugin) for Jenkins which works very nicely in creating links to HTML pages such as:

[image: html publisher results]

Every run, in addition to creating those HTML files, I also create a certain zip file, which is saved within the workspace under "zip" folder:

[image: the zip file in the workspace of this job]

**I would like to allow the users of the job to have a link to download this file, much like the "Automation Log" or "Monitored Events" links. Meaning under "Monitored Events" for example there would be a "Download run zip" tab which, when clicked, will download the zip file for this build.

This will also obviously solve the issue of the workspace being deleted every run and the zip file being lost for previous runs.**

(Having the users access the workspace and manually click the link is not a desired result for me.)

How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are looking for the [Compress Artifacts Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Compress+Artifacts+Plugin)

Comment: I don't believe this answers my question. I am saying I *have* a zip file on my *slave* (not master), and I wish to be able to display it to my user for download for every build, like the HTML pages.

Comment: couldn't you create a the zip artifact and show that instead? Now, I look around my jenkins setup I don't think its possible to do what you are trying to do. (Good question BTW)

Comment: Can you elaborate on how you that? The zip file is basically a certain folder in the workspace zipped.

Comment: My artifacts are on a NFS share. So, when I build my app I have a standard to access them like this, /net/buildsrv/srv/<build.id>/ . Inside that directory is where all my build data is. Its not elegant but very effective.

Comment: I ended up using this plugin, just maybe a little differently. Instead of creating the zip file from my code, I just used this plugin to create it and it looks beautiful on every build =] thanks